# Iframe not loading and showing white background

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

i want to load a specific part of website in iframe, unfortunately iframe is not loading , i have tried object, iframe, framset and jquery too load but i am failed.

I need your help to sort it out and show a specific part from this website
http://www.weddingwire.com/weddings/2816607/wedding_new_website/preview

i need this part of website (http://prntscr.com/30051k)

Please help me .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to embed this website using iframe since it have `X-Frame-Options` header.

You can try displaying it with `curl`.

Comment: I havent any experience in CURL , would you please help me ?

Comment: ah i am junior programmer, and not even understand what is written on website, please help me to give a bit of code then i will try to understand how its getting.